# linq and entity framework data model in .net

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, connection-string

Is there any difference in case of connection string using in Entity Framework Data Model and Linq to SQL?

The connection string in app.config file is shown below

In linq  `<add name="EFProject.Properties.Settings.TestDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=datasourse;Initial Catalog=TestDB;User ID=uname;Password=pwd" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

In entity framework : `<add name="TestDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TestDB.csdl|res://*/TestDB.ssdl|res://*/TestDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=datasourse;initial catalog=TestDBDB;user id=uname;password=pwd;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

The syntax difference means....?

Answer (score 0):

The EntityFramework connection string contains details of the metadata files that define your model. These are the .ssdl, .csdl, and .msl files that are specified. Collectively they make up the edmx file.